# Filter content with pagination

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox filter which filters columns, also I included a pagination. But the pagination is not working that well.
For example I filter 'tag 12', and some columns are left, so the pagination has to adjust to only show the result columns.
If there are more results it must split the results over more pages, if unchecked then restore the columns.

The columns must be limited to only show for example 4 columns on a page.
When the checkboxes are unchecked still they need to show 4 columns a page.

Can you guys help me complete my pagination?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $filterChecks = $('.tag-filters :checkbox');

  $filterChecks.change(function() {

    var classSelectors = $filterChecks.filter(':checked').map(function() {
      return '.' + this.value;
    }).get();

    var $cont = $('.col-md-4');

    if (classSelectors.length) {
      $cont.hide().has(classSelectors.join()).show();
    } else {
      $cont.show();
    }
  });
  
  // pagination
  var totalContent = $(".col-md-4").length;
  var onePageContent = 4;

    $(".items-leading .col-md-4:gt(" + (onePageContent - 1) + ")").hide();
  var totalPage = Math.round(totalContent / onePageContent);

    for(i= 1; i <= totalPage; i++) {
      $(".pagination").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)'>" + i + "</a>");
    }

    $(".pagination a:first").addClass("active");

    $(".pagination a").on("click", function() {
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        var gt = onePageContent * index;

        $(".pagination a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".items-leading .col-md-4").hide();

        for(i = gt - onePageContent; i < gt; i++) {
          $(".items-leading .col-md-4:eq(" + i + ")").show();
        }
    }); // pagination
});
```

```css
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block
}

.pagination a {
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" action="<?php $this ?>">
  <div class="tag-filters">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-10" />Tag 10</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-11" />Tag 11</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-12" />Tag 12</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-13" />Tag 13</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<br /> Pagination:
<div class="pagination">
</div>

<div class="items-leading">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 13</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 13</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
    <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
      <a href="#" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go. I created a function called `createPagination(data)` which accepts a collection of the result elements. This function handles the pagination creation as well as the limitation of 4 results on each page.

This is done by splitting the resulted elements into `chunks`.

I hope this is what you're looking for. Here is the working fiddle:

```js
var size = 4;
var $cont,chunks;
var html = '';
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $cont = $('.col-md-4');
  var filterChecks = $('.tag-filters :checkbox');
  createPagination($cont);
  filterChecks.change(function() {
    html = '';
    var results = [];
    var classSelectors = filterChecks.filter(':checked').map(function() {
     return '.' + this.value;
    }).get();
 
    if(classSelectors.length){
      for(var x = 0; x < $cont.has(classSelectors.join()).length; x++){
        results.push($cont.has(classSelectors.join())[x]);
      }
      createPagination(results);
    } else {
      createPagination($cont);
    }
  });

  $('div.pagination').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $cont.hide();
    $(chunks[parseInt($(this).text())-1]).show();
  });

});

function createPagination(data){
  chunks = new Array(Math.ceil(data.length / size)).fill("").map(function() {
    return this.splice(0, size)
  }, data.slice());
  
  $cont.hide();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++){
    html += '<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</li>';
  }

  $('div.pagination').html(html);
  $(chunks[0]).show();
}
```

```css
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" action="<?php $this ?>">
 <div class="tag-filters">
  <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-10" />Tag 10</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-11" />Tag 11</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-12" />Tag 12</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="tag-13" />Tag 13</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<br />
Pagination:
<div class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
   </li>
   <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 13</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 13</a>
   </li>
   <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div><div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
   </li>
 
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
   </li>
   <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
   </li>
   <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="tags inline">
   <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
    <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, that's amazing. Thank you very much. I learned a lot comparing the old and new code. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. But keep in mind that there are much better ways to achieve what you want to. My answer is a solution to your previous code, however there are better ways ;-). But I am glad that I could help.

Comment: Hi @hallleron Is it possible to add arrow of Next and Previous in pagination?